# Read local file in angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, filereader

I had a requirement of reading users data from `file`, the file can be of any format`(.csv, .xls, ...)`

Users data looks like

```
Name        Email                Number        Image

Yaswanth    yas....@gmail.com    0123456789    file:///home/yash/Desktop/.....jpg
```

When i reach the image value cells i should pick the image file from local path and convert to base64 but i was not able to read rather i get the following error

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

Later i thought i could have one hidden input file and dynamically set the input value and have onchange even but for security reasons the `input type file is read only` so dropped my idea and trying with `FileReader`

Here is the code which i tried

```
  changeListener($event,uploadType) : void {
    this.readThis($event.target,uploadType);
  }
  
  readThis(inputValue: any,uploadType: any): void {
    if(uploadType === 'image') {
      
    }
    if(uploadType === 'file') {
      var file:File = inputValue.files[0];
      this.readThisFile(inputValue);
    }
  }

  readThisFile(inputValue: any): void {
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(inputValue);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
      this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws));
      console.log(this.data);
      this.uploadData(this.data)
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
  }

  uploadData(dataToUpload:any[]) {
    var doublemulUserList = []
        for (let index = 1; index <= dataToUpload.length; index++) {
          this.userObject = {
            "Name": "",
            "Email": "",
            "Number": "",
            "Image": ""
          };
          this.userObject.Name = dataToUpload[index-1]['Name'];
          this.userObject.Email = dataToUpload[index-1]['Email']
          this.userObject.Number = dataToUpload[index-1]['Number']

          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open("GET", dataToUpload[index-1]['Image'], true);
          xhr.responseType = "blob";
          xhr.onload = function (e) {
              console.log(this.response);
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function(event) {
                 var res = event.target.result;
                 console.log(res)
              }
              var file = this.response;
              reader.readAsDataURL(file)
           };
           xhr.send()
        }
  }
```

Can some one share some links or an idea on how to go about this problem.

Comment: Using the browser, there is no way other than using a file input and have the user actively select the file. In order to access the file system natively and still use angular you could try electron and develop a desktop app.

Comment: What if i push the file and images in to a zip file and try reading from zip file? Will that work? @acincognito

Comment: What do you mean by "push file (...) into zip file"? To get a file into the browser the user has to act.

Comment: What i did was instead of uploading csv i was uploading zip file which contains csv file and all the images whose paths are mentioned in file. when i am reading the zip file i am able to read the data of csv and also the images. Is this the right way?? here also i still have issue that reader reads full file at one time not line by line i am still working on it. @acincognito